# Optimizing execution-time to check if chars of a word are in a list python

Tags: python, python-2.7, execution-time

I am writing python2.7.15 code to access chars inside a word. How can I optimize this process, in order to check also if every word is contained inside an external list?

I have tried two versions of python2 code: version(1) is an extended version of what my code has to do, whereas in version (2) I tried a compact version of the same code.

```
chars_array = ['a','b','c']
```

```
VERSION (1)
def version1(word):
    chars =[x for x in word]
    count = 0

    for c in chars:
        if not c in chars_array:
            count+=1

    return count
```

```
VERSION (2)
def version2(word):
    return sum([1 for c in [x for x in word] if not c in chars_array])
```

I am analyzing a large corpus and for version1 I obtain an execution time of 8.56 sec, whereas for version2 it is 8.12 sec.

Comment: If `chars_array` is fixed, and all you're doing with it is seeing if something is inside of it, you first (and probably biggest) optimization will be making it a set instead (`chars_set = set(chars_array)`). It costs O(n) to check for membership in a list, and O(1) for a set (on average; see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: You also don't have to do `chars =[x for x in word]`. That unnecessarily creates another list. Simply remove that and do `for c in word`

Comment: Try removing the square brackets from your version-2 `sum()` expression. That will make it sum over a generator expression rather than a list, reducing the memory allocation overhead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest solution (can be up to 100x faster for an extremely long string):

```
joined = ''.join(chars_array)
def version3(word):
    return len(word.translate(None, joined))
```

Another slower solution that is approximately the same speed as your code:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse
def version4(word):
    return sum(1 for _ in ifilterfalse(set(chars_array).__contains__, word))
```

Timings (`s` is a random string):

```
In [17]: %timeit version1(s)
1000 loops, best of 3: 79.9 µs per loop

In [18]: %timeit version2(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 98.1 µs per loop

In [19]: %timeit version3(s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.12 µs per loop # <- fastest

In [20]: %timeit version4(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 84.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: OP, you can see here Tomothy32 also drops the `[]` brackets in the argument to `sum`. In short, this lets sum iterate directly (so to speak) over the `1`s, rather than constructing an intermediate list; something which might also shave off a couple milliseconds. Here's a demo you can mess around with: https://repl.it/repls/HeftyHandyCygwin

Comment: @wbadart The fastest solution is with `translate`, which I added to my answer.

Comment: pre-compute the `''.join(...)` result rather than performing it every time inside `version3()`

Comment: thanks for your advice. version4 fits very well for my time constraints!

Answer (score 1):

With `chars_array = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']` and `words` equal to a list
of 56048 English words, I measured a number of variants with a command similar to the following at an IPython prompt:

```
%timeit n = [version1(word) for word in words]
```

In each case it reported "10 loops, best of 3", and I have shown the time per loop
in comments next to each function definition below:

```
# OP's originals:

def version1(word):  # 163 ms
    chars =[x for x in word]
    count = 0
    for c in chars:
        if not c in chars_array:
            count+=1
    return count

def version2(word):  # 173 ms
    return sum([1 for c in [x for x in word] if not c in chars_array])
```

Now let's hit `version1` and `version2` with three optimizations:

- remove the redundant list comprehension and iterate through `word` directly instead;
- use the operator `not in` rather than negating the result of the `in` operator;
- check for (non-)membership of a `set` rather than a `list`.

_

```
chars_set = set(chars_array)

def version1a(word):  # 95.5 ms
    count = 0
    for c in word:
        if c not in chars_set:
            count+=1
    return count

def version2a(word):  # 104 ms
    return sum([1 for c in word if c not in chars_set])
```

So there's actually an advantage for the multi-line code over the list comprehension. This may depend on word length, though: `version2a` has to allocate a new list the same length as the word, whereas `version1a` does not. Let's refine `version2a` further to give it that same advantage, by summing over a generator expression rather than a list comprehension:

```
def version2b(word):  # 111 ms
    return sum(1 for c in word if c not in chars_set)
```

To my surprise that was actually slightly counterproductive—but again, that effect may depend on word length.

Finally let's experience the power of `.translate()`:

```
chars_str = ''.join(chars_set)

def version3(word):  # 40.7 ms
    return len(word.translate(None, chars_str))
```

We have a clear winner.